# Injecting values in the DelegatingHandler through IHttpClientFactory

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

When building custom middelware for IHttpClientBuilder, using the DelegatingHandler and IHttpClientFactory.

The constructor of my class looks like this.

```
  public HttpApiFactory(HttpApifactoryConfig config, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        this.config = config;
    }
```

And this is the method called

```
public IApiClient CreateClient(MethodInfo methodInfo, object param, string pipelineName)
    {
        return new Simployer.Service.Client.HttpApiClient(
        httpClientFactory.CreateClient(pipelineName), config.serializer);

    }
```

I know that one of the registred handlers that will be instanciated needs an instance of a given object. This type is not registerd in the IServiceCollection because I have no way of instanciating the class at startup or by a factory.

I want to add the "methodInfo" param to the IServiceContainer, IServiceProvider somehow before calling the httpClientFactory.CreateClient()
I was thinking of IServiceScope, but i can't find a way to insert the instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the constructor to accept a factory that was able to get the values for me.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you could provide a coding sample.